# 404 error while trying to insert an image in a Thymeleaf and Spring Security project

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

Please I really need help.[image]

This is my project's structure and I'm trying to insert a picture into my page like this:

```
<div class="modal-header" align="center">
  <img class="img-circle" id="img_logo" src="../../static/images/asblogo.jpg"
       th:src="@{/images/asblogo.jpg}"/>
</div>
```

in the template login.html. My SecurityConfig and WebMvcConfig look like following:
enter image description here

[image]

[image]
I don't know why I'm still getting either 404 or 302 error.

Please, could you help me? I would be very thankful.
Thank you!!!

Comment: One question: are you getting this error only when you try to add the image to the login page?  What happens when you remove the img tag?  Can you see the login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options to get your image resource:

**Option 1:Map the static resources by your own configuration**

Go to `WebMVCConfig` class and map all the static resources of your web site:

Override the addResourceHandlers method

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}
```

**Option 2: Let Spring map the static resources for you**

In this case just remove de `@EnableWebMvc` annotation from `WebMVCConfig` class

Finally the img tag should look like this:

img tag:

```
<img th:src="@{/images/yourlogo.jpg}" alt="myImage"/>
```

**To Fix the 404 error**

Go to `WebMVCConfig` class and fix the path of login page.  Your are getting the error because Spring try to redirect to `/login` path but that path doesn't exist on `WebMVCConfig` class, instead of `/logout` use `/login` like the following example:

```
   @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
```

Hope it help.

Regards.

Comment: Very good. In that case could you accept this answer as solution? regards